# Trying to make a table cell return to its original state after swipe to reveal in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView where I am using the swipe to delete feature to give the user the option to delete the row.  However, I've also implemented an alert view that is triggered when the user selects delete, asking the user if they are sure, with two buttons, yes or no.  If the user presses yes, the row is deleted, and this is working fine.

However, my problem is that when the user selects no, I am unable to animate the movement of the table cell to return to it's normal, original state while hiding the delete button that it revealed.  My problem is that I want the row to do this after the user presses no on the alert, and for the animation to smooth, just as it worked when the user swiped it initially.

The code I have is the following:

```
- (void) cancelDelete {

    //[self.tableView reloadData];
    //NSLog(@"the indexpath is: %@ ", self.myIndexPath);
    //[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.myIndexPath animated:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.deletedRowIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

}
```

I have left the commented lines in place to show you what I have used/am using.

`[self.tableView reloadData]` returns the cell back to it's original state, but there is no sliding animation of the cell to the right, such that it gradually hides the delete button.  `[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.myIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight]` is what works the closest, but unfortunately, it causes the cell to jerk to the left, and then slide to the right, and I don't want this initial jerking movement.  I honestly thought that `[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.myIndexPath animated:YES]` would work, but unfortunately, it doesn't do anything when it is called. What is it I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reloading is completely the wrong strategy (as you've discovered). Swiping to delete has put the table view cell into `editing` mode. What you want to do is put it back again so that it is no longer in `editing` mode.

There are various ways to do this. You might be able to call `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`. You might be able to call `setEditing:animated:`. In any case, abandon your concentration on reload (which is about *data*) and start experimenting with `editing` mode.

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion, and especially for explaining to me the issue for me to better understand the problem.  I followed your advice, and setEditing:animated did exactly what I was looking for.  You're a gentleman, and a scholar!  Take care.

Comment: This doesn't work if setting editing mode to NO only on the cell. It does work with setting editing to NO also on the tableview the cell is in.